# Group object values by date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I'm trying to make an upcoming event on react native, I have this object

```
const calendatData = [
        {
            "data": [
              {
                "id": 25,
                "title": "Spotify",
                "name": "Family",
                "service_id": 1,
                "repetition": "Monthly",
                "price": "79000",
                "upcoming_date": [
                  "2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 26,
                "title": "Netflix",
                "name": "Mobile",
                "service_id": 2,
                "repetition": "Monthly",
                "price": "49000",
                "upcoming_date": [
                  "2020-08-18T13:35:44.600Z",
                  "2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 27,
                "title": "iTunes",
                "name": "Weekly Special",
                "service_id": 3,
                "repetition": "Weekly",
                "price": "22000",
                "upcoming_date": [
                  "2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z",
                  "2020-08-14T13:35:44.606Z",
                  "2020-08-21T13:35:44.606Z",
                  "2020-08-28T13:35:44.606Z"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "status": "success"
          }
    ]
```

what I've been trying to do is to extract that object based on the `upcoming_date`.
the result that I need is like this

```
upcomingData = [
        {
            date: '2020-08-07',
            title: [
                'Spotify',
                'Netflix',
                'iTunes'
            ]
        },
        {
            date: '2020-08-18',
            title: ['Netflix']
        },
        {
            date: '2020-08-14',
            title: ['iTuunes']
        },
        {
            date: '2020-08-21',
            title: ['iTuunes']
        },
        {
            date: '2020-08-28',
            title: ['iTuunes']
        }
]
```

On the same date, if there are multiple titles, it should be grouped under the same date in the object.

instead what I got was this object

```
upcomingData = [
    {
        title: [
            "Spotify",
            "Netflix",
            "iTunes",
        ],
        date : [
            "2020-08-29",
            "2020-08-07",
            "2020-08-18",
            "2020-08-07",
            "2020-08-07",
            "2020-08-14",
            "2020-08-21",
            "2020-08-28",
        ]
    }
]
```

I am new to this, and I'm aware that this is mostly about javascript knowledge, any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may

- traverse your source array with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) building up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where trimmed portion of your date string is used as a key and the object of desired format as a value
- extract `Map` values, using [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) into resulting array

Following is a quick live demo:

```js
const src = [{"data":[{"id":25,"title":"Spotify","name":"Family","service_id":1,"repetition":"Monthly","price":"79000","upcoming_date":["2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"]},{"id":26,"title":"Netflix","name":"Mobile","service_id":2,"repetition":"Monthly","price":"49000","upcoming_date":["2020-08-18T13:35:44.600Z","2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"]},{"id":27,"title":"iTunes","name":"Weekly Special","service_id":3,"repetition":"Weekly","price":"22000","upcoming_date":["2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z","2020-08-14T13:35:44.606Z","2020-08-21T13:35:44.606Z","2020-08-28T13:35:44.606Z"]}],"status":"success"}],
    
    result = [...src[0].data
      .reduce((r,{upcoming_date, title}) => (
         upcoming_date.forEach((s,_,__,date=s.slice(0,10)) =>
            r.set(
              date, 
              {date, title: [...(r.get(date)?.title||[]), title]}
            )),r),
         new Map())
      .values()
    ]
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This is working for me, I would've never thought of `Array.prototype.reduce()` it's way over my head. I would like to understand this concept and try it multiple times to get the idea. thanks @yevgen-gorbunkov

Comment: `.reduce()` is extremely powerful stuff pretty much for everything that requires turning input array into something new (no matter it's another array, or object or Map) or carry some data throughout the entire loop. Once you feel comfortable using it, you'll never miss the chance to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The ideas are:

- First, iterate your object by [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and set a unique map key from the converted date.
- Then push the title to every map's key.

Actually your final map(here is `myMap`) will be your expected `upcomingData`. To output as your expected object, you can make it in your own way.

```js
const calendarData = [{ "data": [{ "id": 25, "title": "Spotify", "name": "Family", "service_id": 1, "repetition": "Monthly", "price": "79000", "upcoming_date": ["2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"] }, { "id": 26, "title": "Netflix", "name": "Mobile", "service_id": 2, "repetition": "Monthly", "price": "49000", "upcoming_date": ["2020-08-18T13:35:44.600Z", "2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z"] }, { "id": 27, "title": "iTunes", "name": "Weekly Special", "service_id": 3, "repetition": "Weekly", "price": "22000", "upcoming_date": ["2020-08-07T13:35:44.606Z", "2020-08-14T13:35:44.606Z", "2020-08-21T13:35:44.606Z", "2020-08-28T13:35:44.606Z"] }], "status": "success" }];

var myMap = new Map();

calendarData[0].data.map(element => {

    var dates = [];

    element.upcoming_date.map(date => {

        var upcoming_date = date.slice(0,10);

        if (!myMap.get(upcoming_date)) {
            myMap.set(upcoming_date, []);
        }

        dates.push(upcoming_date);

    });

    var len = dates.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        myMap.get(dates[i]).push(element.title);
    }
});

var upcomingData = [];

for (const entry of myMap.entries()) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["date"] = entry[0];
    obj["title"] = entry[1];
    upcomingData.push(obj);
}

console.log(upcomingData);
```

Comment: Messing around with `Date` can make your code [really slooooow](https://jsbench.me/21kcnxk15t/1), should input data get large enough. `.slice()`'ing could work much faster.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, thank you so much. I've updated my answer.

Comment: this is more likely going to be my approach if I knew what am I doing, this is also helping me to understand what's wrong with my own code. Thanks guys

Comment: You can't get one from OP due to insufficient privileges. Nevertheless, you got mine.